# Power Apps: Using a Form to enter data in DataLake, Data Factory or Synapse?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, powerapps

Its possible to create an App or WebForm App using Power Apps to save and retrieve information from Azure DataLake, Synapse or Data Factory?

Could you give any suggestion about this implementations, please?

I appreciate any help you can share!!

Thanks so much!

Comment: what kind of information are you looking to get from Azure DataLake, Synapse or Data Factory? Can you explain your actual goal or requirement ?

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT Thank you for your reply. I Need to save info about the production on my company. That info could be saved in one or more tables keeping a "relation" between them using a keycolumn.  Also I need to make querys to get some data from other tables to get the basis to make the calculation to save my production KPI.   So, My goal is make a CRUD using Power Apps, but I dont know if that if possible using any of the services I already mencioned.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to import and export data into Microsoft Dataverse. You can use dataflows, Power Query, Azure Data Factory, Azure Logic Apps, and Power Automate. See, [Importing and exporting data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/data-platform/import-export-data) and  [Import by bringing your own source file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/data-platform/data-platform-import-export)

You can [configure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/data-platform/create-and-use-dataflows) dataflows to store their data in your organization’s Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 account. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/data-platform/connect-azure-data-lake-storage-for-dataflow) article describes the general steps necessary to do so, and provides guidance and best practices along the way.

Although I a starting in power apps, you can checkout for further [Create, edit, or configure forms using the form designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/model-driven-apps/create-and-edit-forms)

use Dataverse in ADF..

[image]

Add source to your forms...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]